# Remove some string in app inventor when sending it to firebase database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I got a problem when app inventor sends data to my firebase database. I got this output

`["\"https:\\/\\/firebasestorage.googleapis.com\\/v0\\/b\\/sad-police-app.appspot.com\\/o\\/October 6 19:28:1?alt=media&token=d18ae430-c717-45b4-a82a-6dfefc0756dd\""][1]`.

I want to remove all the backslash or `\` so that I can open the link and display the picture. Can anyone help me? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: use regex to remove the symbol you dont want

Comment: okay, noted. thank you so much.